# Real-time Transcoding of Web Video

Tags: video, download, flash, video-streaming

How do I transcode a flash or web video in real-time? I want to be able to watch videos on my TV, which is DLNA compliant, but I'm not sure how to get internet content directly to the TV without first downloading and then converting or serving it.

I want to stream it in real-time to a TV etc (e.g. DLNA compliant device) without having to download it and convert it first.

Comment: Stream it to what? Your question is not very clear at all.

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a DLNA media server to allow your DLNA device to view any content, web or otherwise.

Perhaps the most popular DLNA-compliant server is XBMC, which has plugins adding support for many web sources, including Youtube.

XBMC: http://xbmc.org/
Youtube XBMC Plugin: http://code.google.com/p/youtubexbmc/

If you wish to view videos sourced from other sites, you'll need to find plugins that extend XBMC for that.

Comment: So you want real-time transcoding from a web source to playback on a different device such as a TV coupled with downloading? If you can real-time transcode from a web source do you really need to download the file too, or are you really just trying to watching something from the web on your TV?

Comment: Yes, I can download, but I mean that while I am downloading, I want to stream it to TV etc. I am asking for streaming to a device at the same time with downloading...

Comment: Yes you catch it. I want real-time transcoding from a web source. Do you know a tool, sw that is capable for real-time transcoding ?

Comment: How are you getting the image to your TV?

Comment: I can get or process streams by a media player connected to my TV (or by a DLNA capable TV) But I need a tool running on a PC

Comment: Most of media players have UMSP plugins for some web content such as youtube, apple trailers etc. But I want to stream any flash video in an ordinary web site.(not specialized for UMSP).For example; web clients (e.g. chrome) have plugins to download flash video, but they are just for downloading. I am asking for streaming plugin or etc, not for downloading...

Comment: Then you'll need a server/player with a web  browser that is flash, java, or HTML5 compatible.